# Issue with testing Spring MVC slice in SpringBoot 1.4

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying out the new Spring Boot 1.4 MVC testing features. I have the following controller.

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

  private ProductService productService;

  @Autowired
  public void setProductService(ProductService productService) {
    this.productService = productService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String list(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("products", productService.listAllProducts());
     return "products";
  }
}
```

My minimal ProductService implementation is:

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
  private ProductRepository productRepository;

  @Autowired
  public void setProductRepository(ProductRepository productRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterable<Product> listAllProducts() {
    return productRepository.findAll();
  }

}
```

The code of ProductRepository is:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product,    
 Integer>{
}
```

I'm trying to use the new @WebMvcTest to test the conroller. My view is a thymeleaf teamplate. And my controller test is this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProductController.class)

public class ProductControllerTest {
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ProductController productController= new ProductController();       
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(productController).build();
}

@Test
public void testList() throws Exception {        
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/products"))                 
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())                
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("products"))             
 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("products"));               
 }
}
```

But, on running the test I get this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductService' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [guru.springframework.services.ProductService] found for dependency [guru.springframework.services.ProductService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [guru.springframework.services.ProductService] found for dependency [guru.springframework.services.ProductService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I need help to resolve the issue to properly test ProductController. Suggestions for additional **andExpect()** for more thorough testing of the controller will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using `@WebMvcTest` while also manually configuring a `MockMvc` instance. That doesn't make sense as one of the main purposes of `@WebMvcTest` is to automatically configure a `MockMvc` instance for you. Furthermore, in your manual configuration you're using `standaloneSetup` which means that you need to fully configure the controller that's being tested, including injecting any dependencies into it. You're not doing that which causes the `NullPointerException`.

If you want to use `@WebMvcTest`, and I would recommend that you do, you can remove your `setUp` method entirely and have an auto-configured `MockMvc` instance injected instead using an `@Autowired` field.

Then, to control the `ProductService` that's used by `ProductController`, you can use the new `@MockBean` annotation to create a mock `ProductService` that will then be injected into `ProductController`.

These changes leave your test class looking like this:

```
package guru.springframework.controllers;

import guru.springframework.services.ProductService;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProductController.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void testList() throws Exception {
      mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/products"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("products"))
                 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("products"))
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("products",
                        Matchers.is(Matchers.empty())));

    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `@MockBean` to mock `ProductService` raises a `NullPointerException`, I have posted my code on github [here](https://github.com/ximanta/blog-spring-mvc-test)

Comment: I'd missed that you were manually configuring the `MockMvc` instance. I've updated my answer

Comment: Autowiring MockMvc seems to have enabled security by default and so reports `java.lang.AssertionError: Status Expected :200 Actual :401`. Configuring security by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and overriding `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` to permit all GET request to `/` and `/products` didn't help either. Finally had to disable security through `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)` on the controller test class, and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for solving my core problem of testing an MVC slice.

Comment: I have a setup that seems exactly like your example, but I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for the `Repository` on the `Service`. Is there something additional needed to use the `@MockBean` for the `@Controller` dependencies?

Comment: ^ NVM, looks like an open issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6663

Comment: Same here. I'm using pring-boot 1.5.2 and doing the stuff just like you guys did... and showing the same error

Comment: even if it didn't solve the problem for me, it is a great answer nonetheless. (it seems that the `@WebMvcTest` annotation is still being unable to trigger the loading of all beans)

Answer (score 28):

Who is interested in loading the full application should try using `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` rather than the `@WebMvcTest`.

I have been struggling with the problem for quite a while, but finally I got the complete picture.
The many tutorials on the internet,  <s>as well as the official Spring documentation I found so far</s> , state that you can test your controllers using `@WebMvcTest`; that's entirely correct, still omitting half of the story though.
As pointed out by the javadoc of such annotation, **`@WebMvcTest` is only intended to test your controllers, and won't load all your app's beans at all**, and this is by design.
It is even incompatible with explicit bean scanning annotations like `@Componentscan`.

I suggest anybody interested in the matter, to read the full javadoc of the annotation (which is just 30 lines long and stuffed of condensed useful info) but I'll extract a couple of gems relevant to my situation.

*from [Annotation Type WebMvcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html)*

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent` Filter, `WebMvcConfigurer` and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` beans but not `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans). [...]
>   **If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use MockMVC, you should consider `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` rather than this annotation**.

And actually, only `@SpringBootTest` + `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` fixed my problem, all other approaches that made use of `@WebMvcTest` failed to load some of the required beans.

### EDIT

I take back my comment I made about Spring documentation, because I wasn't aware that a *slice* was implied when one uses a `@WebMvcTest`; actually the MVC slice documentation put it clear that not all the app is loaded, which is by the very nature of a slice.

*[Custom test slice with Spring Boot 1.4](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4)*

> Test slicing is about segmenting the ApplicationContext that is created for your test. Typically, **if you want to test a controller using MockMvc, surely you don’t want to bother with the data layer**. Instead you’d probably want to mock the service that your controller uses and validate that all the web-related interaction works as expected.

Comment: Just right. `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest @AutoConfigureMockMvc` on the test class, and `@Autowired` on `private MockMvc mockMvc;`

Comment: You are a life saver bro!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of auto wiring MockMvc I instantiated mockmvc object in setup phase like this.

```
protected void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have added the following decorators and its still not working:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void somePositiveTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
}
```

make sure you have added the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```